# Scope Interceptor Struts 2: back button behaviour

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, scope, wizard, interceptor

I want to implement a wizard like functionality in my Struts2(2.2.3.1) application using Scope interceptor.

My struts.xml file is as follows:

```
<action name="actionA class="classA" method="methodA">
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />   
    <interceptor-ref name="scope">
        <param name="session">stringA</param>
        <param name="key">consultGuides</param>
        <param name="type">start</param>
    </interceptor-ref>      
    <result>/resultA.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="actionB" class="classA" method="methodB">
    <interceptor-ref name="scope">
        <param name="session">stringA, listA</param>
        <param name="key">consultGuides</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />               
        <result>/resultB.jsp</result>
</action>
    ....
    ....
```

"resultA.jsp" submits to"actionB" populating the "listA". But now if I press the back button(reaching resultA.jsp, where resultA.jsp is just loaded to the browser from its cache without making a new request to the server) and make any changes to the list, the new entries are appended to "listA" instead of entirely replacing it.

The code in 'resultA.jsp' that modifies 'listA' is

```
<s:iterator value="listB"   status="statusB">
    <li>
        <a title="%{varA}">
            <s:checkbox name="listA.id" fieldValue="%{varB}" />
        </a>
    </li>
</s:iterator>
```

I am not implementing SessionAware and just relying on the scopeInterceptor to feed listA to the session.

How can I make it replace the "listA" with the new list in the request?

Answer (score 0):

In order not to allow cached pages after clicking back or forward button of browser, you can try adding some headers in the http response which will clear cache every time you click back or forward button.

This is quite effective if you add this in the interceptor.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
```

By doing this, pressing back button will not load cached page but will make new request to the server.
This should resolve your problem.

Comment: I tried getting the page from the server on pressing the back button. But even refreshing the page manually does not work because the session still continues and the new values are just appended to the variable already in the session.